# python subrpocess.Popen with pipe and stdout redirected to a file in the command not working

Tags: python, scripting, subprocess

Here is the problem

Let's consider a file :

```
printf 'this is \\n difficult' \>test
```

Now I would like to use python with the following bash command:

```
grep 'diff' test |gzip \>test2.gz
```

I have tried the following code which didn't work :

```
import subprocess

command = \['grep', 'diff', 'test', '|', 'gzip', '\>' 'test2.gz'\]

proc = subprocess.Popen(
  command,
  stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
  encoding='utf8', shell=True)
```

I have then tried to redirect the output to a file using:

```
 import subprocess

 command = \['grep', 'diff', 'test', '|', 'gzip'\]

 test2 = open('test2.gz', 'w')

 proc = subprocess.Popen(
    command,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=test2,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    encoding='utf8', shell=True)
```

But it didn't work either, so I am a bit clueless on how to proceed to be able to pipe and redirect to a file.

Comment: what happens with ```command = 'grep diff test | gzip'``` ?

Comment: So weird, it works! any idea of why?

Comment: I have no clue, I just asked a llm out of curiosity ( I am experimenting on basic questions to what extend llms can solve them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't make any sense:

```py
command = ['grep', 'diff', 'test', '|', 'gzip']
```

This is attempting to run the `grep` command with arguments `["diff", "test", "|", "gzip"]` -- which is not what you want -- but when using `shell=True` you need to pass in a string rather than a list.

If you want to use shell scripting features like io redirection, you need to run a shell script.

```py
import subprocess

command = "grep 'diff' test | gzip"

with open('test2.gz', 'w') as test2:
  proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=test2, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, encoding='utf8', shell=True)
```

Comment: With this approach, utmost care needs to be taken if anything about `command` is user-input, or otherwise you have a command injection vulnerability at your hands.

Comment: Also, `command = ['sh', '-c', "grep 'diff' test | gzip"]` without `shell=True` would work (i.e. explicitly using a shell), but the same note about vulnerabilities stands.

Comment: Oh, absolutely. It's best to avoid using `shell=True` and rely on native Python features rather than shell scripts.